# Discord.py Static Timer

Tags: discord.py

How do I have a static timer where the user can just say ??abc and the bot does a countdown from lets say 300s I want the bot to edit the same mssg and not send multiple mssgs thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
@bot.command
async def countdown(ctx, sec:int):
    msg = await ctx.send(f'{sec}s')
    
    for second in range(sec, 0, -1):
        await msg.edit(f'{second}s')

        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is not working as intended.. I dont think you understood my question.. You are also showing variables not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
    @client.command(help="Countdown from specified seconds!")
async def countdown(ctx, t: int):
    msg = await ctx.send(f'Counting down from {t}!')

    while t > 0:
        t -=1
        await msg.edit(content=f'{t} seconds remaining')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await ctx.send(f'Countdown end reached! {ctx.message.author.mention}')
```

Do understand what all this means don't want to spoon-feed anybody ;).
GL

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I understand this code but its not doing what I intended to do...

Comment: @AtharvAgarwal It does exactly what you wanted to do? Create a timer and edit the existing message to reflect the countdown. What is it not doing that you intended to do? Please explain.

Comment: It been a month. I am sorry for the late reply again haha.. Basically what I want to do is for eg. ??abc it starts a timer for 300s what your command does it ??countdown 300 will start the 300s countdown

Comment: Basically what your command does it you say ??countdown <time> and it edits the same mssg to countdown what I want is I do ??countdown and it starts a 300s countdown by default